# How to execute many (~15) bash commands in Perl?

Tags: perl, bash

I know of `system()` and `qx()`, but I need to execute ~15 bash commands. E.g.

`mkdir`, `chown`, `edquota -p user1 -u user2`, `cp -r`, `su - username`, `git`, `rm`, `ln -s`

**Question**

Is there an efficient way to execute many Bash commands in Perl?

I don't care in this case about the output.

Comment: You could put it in a shellscript and execute that with `qx` or `system`...

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that many of the commands that you are running do not require `system()`, they have perl equivalents.  You can `setuid` you can `unlink` you can `mkdir` you can `chown` etc, all directly from perl.  Of the commands you've pasted, `edquota` and `git` are probably the only ones that would be easiest to implement via `system`

Comment: Even git has [modules that wrap it](https://metacpan.org/search?q=git)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'd use the equivalent Perl function for as many of those bash command as I could, which is most of the ones you included in your post.  Then, for the rest of them I'd either use system() or qx() or backticks or one of the IPC:: modules (such as IPC::Run or IPC::Open3).

Answer (score 1):

Use bash syntax for many commands. Separate them with `;` or `&&` or whatever takes your fancy (`man bash`).

```
$ perl -E 'system qq{date; date}'
```

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, I like POE framework's [POE::Wheel::Run](http://search.cpan.org/~rcaputo/POE-1.354/lib/POE/Wheel/Run.pm) module for running system commands (and code blocks) asynchronously. You say you do not care about the output, but if you need it in the future POE::Wheel::Run has an elegant interface allowing us to interact with the process.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $s = <<END;
echo "1"
echo "2"

echo "3"
END

system("$s");
```