# Does Perl have su or similar command?

Tags: linux, perl, bash, ubuntu, centos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to successfully run Perl script with setuid() when used as cgi-bin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991001/how-to-successfully-run-perl-script-with-setuid-when-used-as-cgi-bin)

I am running my Perl script as root, and would like to have these commands run as `$USER`

```
mkdir bin
cp -r /opt/gitolite .
gitolite/install -ln
gitolite setup -pk ${USER}.pub
rm ${USER}.pub

mkdir -p .gitolite/hooks/common
ln -s /opt/pre-receive .gitolite/hooks/common/
```

**Question**

Does Perl have a `su -c "mkdir bin" $USER` or something similar?

Comment: You can set the effective user id by the special variable $>

Comment: By the way I think this question is for askubuntu.com

Comment: @rekire: Why askubuntu? It's equally valid for any Unix-like system.

Comment: This must be the follow-up of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178485/how-to-execute-many-15-bash-commands-in-perl. What happened to the built-ins?

Comment: @nickisfat, why comment not answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the special variable `$>` . See: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Comment: Can you give an example? I can't figure out how to use it from the link, and Google doesn't return anything useful with this.

Comment: Each user has a numeric uid (which you can get in the /etc/passwd file).  Say user Harry has uid = 56.  If your Perl script does $> = 56 then the script is now running as Harry.  This will only work if your script originally started running as root.